# Is it possible to change the scale of UIWebView after loading an online web page?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I would like users to pinch in my `UIWebView` and already set the `ScaleToFitPages` to YES.

The page content does not contains anything like

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initianl-scale=1; maximum-scale:4; ....'>
```

Could I use any javascript code(jquery or not with jquery) to change the scale to original scale(1:1) after the page loaded(eg. in the delegate method `didFinishLoading`...)

Answer (score 0):

In UIWebViewDelegate , there is protocol `webViewDidFinishLoad:`that will be call after a web view finishes loading a frame.

so you can put some javascript that custom the scale

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"your javascript code" ];`